# Springboot closing context in the middle of test execution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In a test suite of 500 tests we are experiencing that before all the tests are finished, the Spring context is closed, deleting the H2 tables and producing the corresponding exception.

I can see the following trace

```
2023-08-25 17:46:47.964 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2023-08-25 17:46:47.964 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2023-08-25 17:46:47.964 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext [558418084] in cache under key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@33dd1e38 testClass = RelationshipNewE2ETest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.anjana.core.kerno.KernoApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{new}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@57ac5227, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@1ae67cad, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@612ff157, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@655f7ea, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@20a14b55, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@488eb7f2, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@5af97850], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
2023-08-25 17:46:47.980 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@2e51d054, started on Fri Aug 25 17:38:21 CEST 2023, parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1f52eb6f
2023-08-25 17:46:47.980 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'springCloudAzureCredentialTaskExecutor'
2023-08-25 17:46:47.980 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2023-08-25 17:46:48.011  INFO 32464 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-25 17:46:48.011 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
drop table if exists db.table CASCADE 
2023-08-25 17:46:48.011 DEBUG 32464 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        :
```

When the test subsequently inserts data into the table, the exception that the table does not exist is raised.

Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks in advance

I have removed several existing @DirtyContext as well as removed the dependency on devtools

It is always failing the same tests. If I run them in isolation they work correctly so I assume they share the same context in which the tables have been deleted. Here is an example of a test that is failing to preload the data before the test

```
 @Test
 @Sql(scripts = {"/scripts/test/data_relationship_modify_workflow.sql"},
      executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
  void testCheckSimpleEntityProperties_KO_Name() {
......
}
```

Comment: Is it always the same test that is ending, then? Or is it a random one? Can you provide us an example of test showing us the line where it stops?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I have edited the question by adding the required information

Comment: Plenty of sql statements without commit, and after a bunch of them, a automatic rollback that stops a transaction becoming to large? It's just one idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MarcLeBihan but the real problem is that the tables are been deleted, and as far i know, this is due to a context shutdown

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Finally I was able to check what was going on. We are making an incorrect use of the context cache in the springboot tests and we generate too many. As soon as we reached the preset limit of the cache it removed one according to LRU and when that one was removed is when the context is closed deleting the tables. Increasing the maximum value of the cache (to 64 to test) has been solved. The following system property is needed -Dspring.test.context.cache.maxSize=64 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/ctx-management/caching.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to increase the max size of the context cache in the spring tests with the following system property

```
spring.test.context.cache.maxSize=64
```

It is not the most correct solution since what we would have to do is to minimize the number of contexts used to optimize the use of the cache.